# Android Chat implementation Suggestions

Tags: android, chat

I have been working on a chat application and I need some suggestions to go about it. I have a server. Whenever a user logs into my app, and selects some user by searching, and sends a message to him, it will be stored on the server. Then my app checks if any a new message has arrived for me. If any message comes, it will be notified to the user. For achieving this, I have followed [this method](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/) to update the UI whenever a new message comes.

And when the chat continues for more than 3 minutes, the app starts becoming slow. How to go about the problem?

Comment: I am just start working on the similar type chat(multiuser) application, can you please help me how to built chat application in `Android` because android doesn`t have inbuilt `push notification` system like `iphone`. I want to use my own server that`s why i can not use 3ed part API. I am using php server & create my chat`s data base. How i begin to start now onward...??? I pleased You to help me to solve this Problem! @Dinesh

Comment: @RupeshYadav sure i can help you... please go through [transcript mode](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/listview-transcript-mode) and [update UI from background services](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/)... this two links will help... if you need any more support let me know...

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks a lot! I have started working as you have mentioned & would appreciate your response in future for any further query related , Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Hi @Dinash, Hope you are good - The things you have mentioned about android chat system , really worked thanks a ton for that.
Dinash i have some more doubts and for that i'll really appreciate if you can provide me your contact details so that i can mail you my queries at once whithout interrupting again n again :) , I hope you dont mind.

Comment: @RupeshYadav you can get my [contact details from here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/709406/dinash)

Comment: Hi @Dinesh, your mail id is not visible on your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/709406/dinash), please send me a test mail on my id `rupesh.pcst@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is sluggish that means there is a memory leak somewhere, or you are over logging, or doing something that you shouldn't be doing on the UI thread. Maybe you're polling the server too much?

By the way using TextView for chat is primitive, use the [transcript mode](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/listview-transcript-mode) for ListViews.

Comment: Thanks @Reno i tried with transcript mode and it worked but still need to test the performance of the module in the app. And i am retrieving the chat data from server for every 30 Sec and resetting the listview if any new message has come..